# TypeError: input() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, typeerror, eric-ide

I'm trying to learn basics of python and there is this `input()` command in eric6 and the command and the error is this:

```
size  = int(input('size: '))
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\eric6\DebugClients\Python\DebugClientBase.py", line 74, in DebugClientInput
    return DebugClientInstance.input(prompt, echo)
TypeError: input() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you sure you saved and ran the right file?

Comment: Have you defined another function called input above this function call?

Comment: Looks like this isn't the builtin input function

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Eric IDE to me. I can indeed see that the IDE source code [defines an `input()` method with no `echo` argument](https://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/hg/eric/file/tip/eric6/DebugClients/Python/DebugClientBase.py#l287) but that other code [tries to call it with an `echo` argument](https://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/hg/eric/file/tip/eric6/DebugClients/Python/DebugClientBase.py#l74).

Comment: Perhaps use a different IDE for now.

Comment: Although it looks like this issue has been present [since 2016](https://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/hg/eric/diff/5f56410e7624/DebugClients/Python/DebugClientBase.py).

Comment: @en_lorithai: this is an internal hook in the Eric IDE they are using to run their code, nothing in the user code itself.